# Add multiple 1D arrays to a 2-D array

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array, export-to-excel

I am working on automating a large spreadsheet tab with macros. I have created a macro for each column because each column processes data in its own way.

Here is how I do it: I have created a main subroutine that calls the subroutine for each column. To optimize the execution time, I import the data I need in tables, then according to my code I fill in a result table and copy it to the relevant column. The process works very well because it takes less than 2 seconds to do it with a column of 52000 rows, but as I am working with 40 columns, at the end I have a macro that takes 1min20s.

The main problem with my code is that I am copying my result tables in each column one by one, which takes a lot of time. The solution would be to create a final table that would receive each table and then paste the final table directly into the range of my Excel tab.

I am working on it, but I would like to know which is the (best) solution to create a multi-dimensional array from multiple 1D-arrays.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
Public Sub traitement_Bouton()
    ' >>> DEFINITION DES WORKSHEETS <<<
    Dim wsht_Eol As Worksheet, wsht_DATA As Worksheet
    Set wsht_Eol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Eolienne")
    Set wsht_DATA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
    
    ' >>> LANCEMENT DU CHRONO ET COUPURE DU REPEINT ECRAN <<<
    debut = Timer
    Call MilliSecondTimer_Start
    Call shut_Down
    
    ' >>> DEFINITION DU NBR DE LIGNES ET DE COLONNES DE "DATA" <<<
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RowCount_DATA As Long, ColumnCount_DATA As Long
    With wsht_DATA
        RowCount_DATA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row            'COMPTE LE NOMBRE DE LIGNES
        ColumnCount_DATA = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'COMPTE LE NOMBRE DE COLONNES
    End With
    ' >>> DEFINITION DU NBR DE LIGNES ET DE COLONNES DE "Eolienne" <<<
    Dim RowCount_Eol As Long, ColumnCount_Eol As Long
    With wsht_Eol
        RowCount_Eol = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row            'COMPTE LE NOMBRE DE LIGNES
        ColumnCount_Eol = .Cells(14, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'COMPTE LE NOMBRE DE COLONNES
    End With
    ' >>> DEFINITION DES TABLEAUX <<<
    Dim tab_Date() As Variant, tab_Heure() As Variant, tab_Null() As Variant, tab_Puissance() As Variant
    tab_Date = wsht_DATA.Range("B10:B" & RowCount_DATA) 'RECUPERE TOUTES LES DATES
    tab_Heure = wsht_DATA.Range("C10:C" & RowCount_DATA) 'RECUPERE TOUTES LES HEURES

    tab_Null = wsht_Eol.Range("J15:J" & RowCount_Eol) 'RECUPERE TOUTES LES VALEURS DE LA COL. J
    tab_Puissance = wsht_Eol.Range("K14:K" & RowCount_Eol) 'RECUPERE TOUTES LES SOMMES DE PUISSANCE DE COL. K

    Call colonne_Date_Heure(wsht_Eol, tab_Date(), tab_Heure(), i)
    Call colonne_HL(wsht_Eol, RowCount_Eol, tab_Null(), tab_Puissance(), i)


    Call MilliSecondTimer_End

    duree = Format((Timer - debut) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
    MsgBox "Vérification terminée !" & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "Durée : " & duree & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "Durée en s: " & result
    Call switch_On
End Sub
 
'DATE AND HOUR COLUMN
Public Sub colonne_Date_Heure(Ws_Eol As Worksheet, tableauDATE() As Variant, tableauHEURE() As Variant, i As Long)

    Dim rgCondition As Range
    Set rgCondition = Ws_Eol.Range("I2")
    
    Dim tab_resultat() As Variant
    ReDim tab_resultat(1 To UBound(tableauDATE, 1), 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(tableauDATE, 1)
        If rgCondition = 0 Or rgCondition = Month(tableauDATE(i, 1)) Then
            tab_resultat(i, 1) = tableauDATE(i, 1)
        Else
            tab_resultat(i, 1) = ""
        End If
    Next i

Ws_Eol.Range("G15").Resize(UBound(tableauDATE, 1)) = tab_resultat ' Ws_Eol.Range("G15").Resize(UBound(tableauDATE, 1)) = tab_result 'RESIZE PERMET D'ETENDRE LA PLAGE DE RECUP DE DONNES A LA TAILLE DE tab_Date
Ws_Eol.Range("H15").Resize(UBound(tableauHEURE, 1)) = tableauHEURE  'RESIZE PERMET D'ETENDRE LA PLAGE DE RECUP DE DONNES A LA TAILLE DE tab_Date

End Sub

'HL COLUMN
Public Sub colonne_HL(Ws_Eol As Worksheet, NB_row_Eol As Long, tableauNUL() As Variant, tableauPUISS() As Variant, i As Long)
    Dim tab_result() As Variant
    ReDim tab_result(1 To UBound(tableauNUL, 1))
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(tableauNUL, 1)
        If tableauPUISS(i + 1, 1) = "hors ligne" Then
            tab_result(i) = 1
        ElseIf tableauPUISS(i + 1, 1) = 0 And tableauNUL(i, 1) < 5 Then
            tab_result(i) = 1
        Else
            tab_result(i) = 0
        End If
    Next i
Ws_Eol.Range("I15").Resize(NB_row_Eol - 14) = Application.Transpose(tab_result) 'AFFECTE LE TABLEAU A LA COLONNE ENTIERE DE I15 JUSQU'A I52078
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple 1D arrays for the output, create a single 2D array of the correct dimensions, and populate that from the source data.

The populated array can be added to the output sheet in one operation. That is, assuming there is no pre-existing data on the output sheet which needs to remain unaffected and is "in the middle of" the output range for your 2D results array.

Here is a very basic example, processing data from A1:E20 into a 3-column output table.
Input test data is just a range full of `=RAND()`

```vb
Sub ArrayExample()

    Dim arrIn, arrOut, i As Long
    
    arrIn = Sheet1.Range("A1:E20").Value        'read all input data
    
    ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arrIn, 1), 1 To 3) 'for example: 3 output columns
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrIn, 1)
    
        If arrIn(i, 1) < 0.5 And arrIn(i, 2) > 0.5 Then
            arrOut(i, 1) = "Y"
        Else
            arrOut(i, 1) = "N"
        End If
        
        If arrIn(i, 3) > 0.5 And arrIn(i, 4) < 0.5 Then
            arrOut(i, 2) = 1
        End If
        
        If arrIn(i, 5) < 0.2 Then arrOut(i, 3) = "OK"
    
    Next i
    
    'write the output table
    Sheet1.Range("G1").Resize(UBound(arrOut, 1), UBound(arrOut, 2)).Value = arrOut
    
End Sub
```